# Get files from locate , Then remove them

Tags: linux, bash

After removing packages , some of them leave files behind that i don't really use , so i want to remove them rather than restoring the whole server from scratch.

I use

```
sudo locate logstash
```

I get a long list of files and directories , and i want to delete them.

There is an oldschool way that i've seen , and that's putting this list to a file.txt and then read it line by line and remove it.

Is there any faster bash way to remove these items shown in this list?

In addition , how can i tell if it's a directory or a file ? ( to remove simply or recursive )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
locate logstash | xargs -I{} rm -rf {}
```

*Note:*
Make sure that `locate` gives you valid files that you want to delete.

Comment: Personally I would add the -I argument just to be safe. locate logstash | xargs rm -rfI

Answer (score 2):

It's better to be safe than sorry:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo locate -0 logstash >> /tmp/logstash                      # Null separated to tmp file
xargs -0 -I {} -n1 -P0 echo {} < /tmp/logstash                # Print list to check

read -p "Do you want to DELETE these items (Y/N)?" 
[ "$(echo $REPLY | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])" == "y" ] || exit  # Verify

xargs -0 -I {} -n1 -P0 sudo rm -rf {} < /tmp/logstash         # Same list to delete
```

It is good practice, when using `xargs` and files, to use null-separated lists, as described in the man page (my emphasis):

> Because  Unix  filenames  can contain blanks and newlines, this
>   default
>          behaviour is often problematic; filenames containing blanks and/or newlines  are  incorrectly  processed by `xargs`.  In these situations **it is
>          better to use the `-0` option**, which prevents such problems.   When using
>          this option you will need to ensure that the program which produces the
>          input for `xargs` also uses a null character as  a  separator.   If  that
>          program  is GNU `find` for example, the `-print0` option does this for you.

`locate` has the `-0` option to output accordingly.

Comment: I'd write the prompt as `[y/N]` to indicate that anything not matching `y` is considered to be `n` - this is a common convention with interactive programs.

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight ,  as in case sensitive ?

Comment: No, the convention is to write the default in upper-case, but to accept either case.  Some scripts then use `case "$REPLY" in [Yy]*) true ;; *) exit ;; esac`, for example.

Comment: Sorry .. are you able to point out how that isn't the case currently ?  anything not matching `y` presently exits.

Comment: That is the case currently, and I'm not suggesting you change that.  I'm just proposing a tiny improvement in *how you indicate that to the user* in the prompt message.  It's arguably just cosmetic, but it is a convention that has some value.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

*This answer assumes the use of GNU coreutils.  Some of the options presented here are GNU extensions to the POSIX standard, and are not present in other implementations.*

`xargs` is the tool to convert standard input to program arguments.

To use it safely, you'll want to invoke `locate` with `-0` to produce null-separated output, and `xargs` also with `-0` to understand null-separated input.  This allows your filenames to contain any whitespace (including newlines) without problem.

We'll also pass `-r` to xargs, so we don't run `rm` if there are no matches

Although `locate` always outputs absolute pathnames, it's a good habit to explicitly separate options from arguments with `--`, so as to avoid surprises with names that begin with `-`.

I would also consider using the `-I` option to `rm`, to ask for confirmation of the files to be deleted if there are more than three arguments, or if any is a directory.

With all that considered, you get

```
locate -0 logstash | xargs -r0 rm -Ir --
```